# Codeigniter: Redirect predefined urls to default controller's method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

There are two predefined URLs which I want to redirect to default controller's method and return default responses. URLs are:

> **URL 1:** `http://EnrollmentService.mydomain.com/EnrollmentServer/Discover.svc`
> (GET request)
>
> **URL 2:** `https://EnrollmentService.mydomain.com/EnrollmentServer/Discover.svc` (POST request)

I tried adding following to `.htaccess` file but no luck.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /testsaav/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    Redirect /enrollmentserver/Discover.svc http://localhost/projectname/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Right now I am trying to redirect `http://localhost/projectname/EnrollmentServer/Discover.svc` to default controller's index method.
I have created a project with default controller name `enrollmentserver.php` but when I tried to access `http://localhost/projectname/enrollmentserver`, I got **Object not found error**

How would redirect both the urls to default controller's any method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the default CI routes system. In your application/config/routes file:

```
$route['EnrollmentServer/Discover.svc'] = "projectname";
```

Or generically:

```
$route['EnrollmentServer/:any'] = "projectname";
```

Assuming "projectname" is the controller you want to route to